# How to change the shape of app icon in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am making an app icon in flutter. And I have a problem. I want to make my app icon with square shape. But I am just getting the circle shape icon.

[image: The Icon I am trying to implement]

[image: The Icon I am getting]

How can i change the shape of the icon?

Answer (score 4):

You can't change the shape of app icon by coding.

So, what you can do is that:

1. Make a circular icon with it's background transparent
2. Save it and drag & drop that image file [here](https://appicon.co/)

3. Generate the icon, it will download a zip file
4. Extract the **android** folder from that (other files are not necessary)
5. Copy all the contents ("mipmap-" folders) from the android folder (it's basically the different icon sizes)
6. Go to **res** folder in your project location -> F:\flutter\project_name\android\app\src\main\res
7. And replace all **mipmap-** folder with the new one which has your created logo

This may help you

Comment: Thanks for replaying. I've been searching for that. Now I know it's not concern with the coding. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I think it's set up automatically by Google through *Adaptive Icons*.

So your app Icon will automatically change based on your device theme, setting, etc.
You don't need to worry about that. All you need to do is provide a square app icon.

In your image, you can look at the YouTube icon. It's basically a square, but because it's adaptive (automatically as long as you set it up correctly), it could transform into several different shapes.

You can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/google-play/resources/icon-design-specifications), or [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. But you need to have sdk higher than 26.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hpQenyqxTmw

Answer (score 0):

After you generate your app icons from: https://appicon.co/, simply replace all folders contained in zip for android with the already existing folders in res directory .

Then go to app>src>main>res
Right-click on res and select new> image asset.
Adjust the icon to how you want it to appear.